# Installing Python 3.4.3 does not place py.exe in Windows root directory

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, installation

Articles such as https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/ and http://testerstories.com/2014/06/multiple-versions-of-python-on-windows/ speak about how the new Windows installer for Python (3.3+) should place "py.exe" and "pyw.exe" into the Windows %SYSTEMROOT% directory - so that it works even if PATH is not set to the python install directory.

I have now installed Python 3.4.3 on Windows 7 and Windows 8, following the default in both cases (Register Extensions = Yes, Set PATH var = No). However py.exe is not placed in the %SYSTEMROOT% directory in both cases.

(Maybe I need to run as admin?, however I am promoted about this anyway when trying to install, and there is no such right-click item for the installer file)

What is wrong? Should I just copy these 2 files (py.exe and pyw.exe) to the %SYSTEMROOT% manually? Has something changed in 3.4.3 with regards to this?

Comment: You have to install for all users.

Comment: I see. I specifically chose "this user only". You should post that as an answer then!